# Javascript OOP private functions

Tags: javascript, function, oop, private

I would like to create a constructor which can be instantiated with a json file which then is used by some private functions which in the end pass their results to a public function of the prototype. Is this the right approach?

Here more specific code:

```
//constructor
function queryArray(json){
    this.json = json;

    //init qry template with default values
    function qryInit() {
        var qryTemplate = {
            //some stuff
        }
        return qryTemplate;
    }

    //generate array of request templates
    function qryTempArray(json){
        var template = qryInit();
        var qryTempArray1 = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
            qryTempArray1.push({
                'SearchIndex': json[i].SearchIndex,
                'Title': json[i].Title,
                'Keywords': json[i].Keywords,
                'MinimumPrice': json[i].MinimumPrice,
                'MaximumPrice': json[i].MaximumPrice,
                'ResponseGroup': template.ResponseGroup,
                'sort': template.sort
            });
        }
        return qryTempArray1;
    }
}

//function for finally building all the queries
queryArray.prototype.qryBuilder = function(){
    var qryTempArray1 = [];
    qryTempArray1 = qryTempArray(this.json);
    //other stuff
}
```

If I call the qryBuilder function on an Object, I get an error
in the function qryTempArray at the json.length in the for loop (undefined).
Why that?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve dependency injection, or what?

Comment: you have missed closing curly bracket. Edit your code

Comment: `query` is spelt with a single *r*, constructor names should be capitalised while instances should be lowercase, there's a missing closing brace, and you could improve your indentation, but apart from that your code is fine.

Comment: You should just use typescript which supports ES6 syntax. The result will still be javascript (ES5)

Comment: Thank you so long; why do you recommend to use typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the code is written above, I'm surprised you even get to the loop.  It would seem you'd get undefined when you called qryBuilder();
I would expect something along the lines of the following to work.

```
//constructor
function queryArray(json) {
    var self = this;
    self.json = json;

    //init qry template with default values
    self.qryInit = function() {
        var qryTemplate = {
            //some stuff
        }
        return qryTemplate;
    }

    //generate array of request templates
    self.qryTempArray = function(json) {
        var template = self.qryInit();
        var qryTempArray1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            qryTempArray1.push({
                'SearchIndex': json[i].SearchIndex,
                'Title': json[i].Title,
                'Keywords': json[i].Keywords,
                'MinimumPrice': json[i].MinimumPrice,
                'MaximumPrice': json[i].MaximumPrice,
                'ResponseGroup': template.ResponseGroup,
                'sort': template.sort
            });
        }
        return qryTempArray1;
    }
    return self;
}
queryArray.prototype.qryBuilder = function() {
    var qryTempArray1 = [];
    qryTempArray1 = this.qryTempArray(this.json);
    return qryTempArray1;
}
var q = new queryArray([{
    'SearchIndex': 0,
    'Title': 'foo',
    'Keywords': 'testing',
    'MinimumPrice': 20,
    'MaximumPrice': 40
}]);
console.log(q);
console.log(q.qryBuilder());
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly? To solve this, I need a priviledged function?

Comment: From your original code, I don't see how your prototype function would be able to access qryTempArray() otherwise. Functions defined on a prototype are not defined within the scope of the constructor of queryArray, and will not have access to the constructor's local\private variables

Comment: That is exactly where I was wrong. I thought the functions of the prototype share the scope of the constructor as well as the private variables and functions. Thank you! But one further question. If I change my code in a way that every function is defined on the prototype, it works wihout this/self...why can that be if the prototype-functions do not share the sope of the constructor?

Comment: When you create the instance of queryArray properties from prototype are copied to the object.  Prototype properties can implicitly access one from another simply by using "this". [This](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/understanding-javascript-prototypes) is a decent overview of prototypes.